# what is windows conversion for bytes to mb?

Tags: c#, windows, filesize, fileinfo

What is windows converion for converting bytes to MB?
The calculated size of my folder is (1,568,653,060 bytes)

```
// 1.
// Get array of all file names.
string[] a = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*");

// 2.
// Calculate total bytes of all files in a loop.
long b = 0;
foreach (string name in a)
{
// 3.
// Use FileInfo to get length of each file.
  FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
  b += info.Length;
}

//b = 1568653060

//However, googles conversion...convert 1568653060 bytes to mb
//returns 
//1568653060 b = 1568.65306 mb
```

but according to my calculations

```
// Return total size in MB int
float mbValue =  (b / 1024f) / 1024f;
//mbValue = 1495.98413
//should return 1496 mb
```

BUT windows returns....
size: 1.45 GB (1,568,653,060 bytes)
Size on disk: 1.46 GB (1,568,686,080 bytes)
//converting this to MBs gives me 1460 MB....

where is the other 36Mb come out of?
I just need it to be exact...which method should I stick to?
Setting limits on user file uploads

Comment: When you say *"windows returns..."* I'm going to assume that you meant *File Explorer*. In that case: [How does Explorer calculate “Size on disk”?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160427-00/?p=93365), [How does Explorer calculate the folder size information in the folder tooltip?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120503-00/?p=7713), [Why can’t Explorer decide what size a file is?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110315-00/?p=11223).

Comment: For me 1,568,653,060 / 1024/1024 = 1495.98 - so it rounded down  google has used 1000 not 1024.

Comment: Once upon a time there was someone who thought it was necessary to make a distinction between Mega (1.000.000) and Mebi (2^20) Bytes. This has cause some people to believe it is sensible to use 1.000 as a factor to denote Bytes instead of the well established 1024 (2^10). Stick to 1024 if you don't want people to laugh at you.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer where have I used 1000?...float mbValue =  (b / 1024f) / 1024f;...google was just put in as an example the Q was why is my calculation different from the windows file explorer

Comment: @John Goggle uses 1000 (if you specify MB instead of MiB), you use 1024 and the extra MBs come from every single File rounded up to the next full segment on your disk (that's why Size and Size on Disk are different)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer displays megabytes, but calculates mebibytes So dividing by 1024 for each successive unit is correct.

Size on disk includes space that has to be part of the files for technical reasons, such as the last page if it's not completely full. It also includes other streams than just `$DATA` if they exist. It can even show 0 bytes for a file that fits completely in its directory entry. But as a general rule, that number will always be different than the file content size.